# Would it be possible to have such function?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

Let $u$ be a (measurable) function in interval $(0,1)$. I am wondering would it be possible for $u$ to have following properties:
$$
\int_0^1u\,dx=0,
$$
and
$$
\int_0^{\frac12}u\,dx<0,\,\,\,\int_{\frac12}^1u\,dx>0
$$
and
$$
\int_0^{\frac14}u\,dx<0,\,\,\,\int_{\frac14}^{\frac12}u\,dx>0,\,\,\int_{\frac12}^{\frac34}u\,dx<0,\,\,\int_{\frac34}^{1}u\,dx>0
$$
and
$$
\int_0^{\frac18}u\,dx<0,\,\,\,\int_{\frac18}^{\frac14}u\,dx>0,\,\,\int_{\frac14}^{\frac38}u\,dx<0,\,\,\int_{\frac38}^{\frac12}u\,dx>0,\ldots...
$$
If yes, what this function looks like? Do they have a name? Thank you!

Comment: The first idea - try $f(x) - \frac 12$ where $f$ is some variant of the Cantor's stairs function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not possible.  Since $\int_0^1 u\,dx = 0$ is given, we have
$u$ is integrable.  That is, $\int_0^1 |u|\,dx < +\infty$.  Also
$$
0 > \int_0^{1/2} u\;dx > \int_0^{1/2^2} u\;dx > \int_0^{1/2^3} u\;dx > \dots
$$
But these converge to zero by dominated convergence.  A decreasing sequence of negative numbers cannot converge to zero.

Comment: What tells you that $|u|<g$ where $g$ is integrable?

Comment: I got confused sir. Say, $u\equiv -1$ on $(0,1/2)$ and $1$ on $(1/2,0)$. Then I have $0>\int_0^{1/2^n}udx$ for any $n>0$. But I don't think I can push to the limit.

Comment: No, I meant integrable as in $\int_0^1 gdx < \infty$. Isn't that needed for the dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: Oh, excuse me. I forgot that the integral of a function is defined only when $\int f^+$ or $\int f^-$ is integrable.

Comment: $\int_0^{1/2}udx>\int_0^{1/4}udx$ is the same as $\int_{1/4}^{1/2}u\,dx > 0$.

Comment: Sir. I understand your answer and I am willing to accept it. But I also like to relax my requirement a bit. My initial idea is to have $\int_0^1u=0$ but $u$ is not integrable, so no dominated convergence. I am thinking some function that oscillate so much and hence might be do my job. So, do you want me to accept your answer and start a new problem, or I just go ahead and edit this question?

Comment: Why not post it as a new question.  But what kind of integral will that be?  Maybe for a gauge integral you can have $\int u$ defined, even though $\int |u| = \infty$??  Or maybe just an improper Riemann integral?